# Is there a way to do a call graph of c++ code in R?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, call-graph

I'm a daily user of R but very new to c++. I'm using Rstudio to explore a very large and complicated C++ code by using  R and Shell tools like ctags, grep and the `system` function. To better understand the code, i would like to understand the call hierarchy by building a call tree of that code. **Is there a simple way to do that in R, e.g. with Rcpp?**

Ultimately, i would like to be able to follow a parameter by coloring/ extracting the parts of the code that contains it (and still seeing the call hierarchy between the routines the parameter is mentioned in)

FYI:
So far i have tried to use Vim cctree to get the call tree from the main(), and transferred the list result to R and then to a graph with igraph, but this method has a lot of intermediate steps that make it hard to repeat.
Also, from R, i'm using ctags to find all the routines and i'm thinking i could use grep to find the various occurences of the routine, detect where it is defined and where it is called, but i don't know exactly how to do that.

Sorry if the question is quite vague. I guess, in short, i'm hoping that there is already a way to explore C++ code in R.
Thanks!

Comment: About fifteen or so years ago I have a few tutorials on high(er)-performance computing with R which covered Google perftools (and slides should still be on ny website). It can generate data that feeds into graphviz, see e.g. this more recent tutorial: https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php?title=Profiling_with_GPerfTools  The problem is, though, that there are too many intermediate R calls dealing with its R's internals that get in the way.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm not yet looking at running the code from R, just to explore it and understand the structure. This is closer to simple text analysis than really connected R to C